# Performance: Create indices after or before converting from UNLOGGED to LOGGED?

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, transaction-log

I'm working on a software that initially populates tables with a lot of data (bulk mode), after which it switches to "normal" mode of operation.

To make bulk mode fast, I'm starting with UNLOGGED tables with almost no indices (among other things).

After loading all the initial data I switch to  to normal mode: I'm creating indices and altering the tables to be LOGGED again.

My question is: performance wise - is there any difference in order of creating indices and changing to LOGGED tables? From reliability perspective, it seems that the fastest I switch to LOGGED, the better (lower chance of loosing all my precious data). But will I have to pay for it in time it takes to create all the indices?

In my initial tests, it seems that `ALTER TABLE x SET LOGGED` is taking quite a bit of time, which I don't understand because I thought it affects only operations after it, and in itself is *almost* an NO-OP.

My PG is:

> PostgreSQL 9.6.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.0, 64-bit

though I'm asking more generally. Any links to things that would help my understand what exactly is going on with `UNLOGGED` and `LOGGED` (especially in combination with indicies) would be also appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You will not gain as much as you think if you load data into an unlogged table and then change it to a logged one, no matter at which point you create the indexes.

The benefit of unlogged tables is that no WAL (transaction log) is written. But when you turn an unlogged table into a logged one, WAL *for the complete table and its indexes* will be written. This is necessary, because now PostgreSQL has to be able to recover the table in case of a crash.

Your gain is that the WAL will be written block-wise instead of row by row.

Unlogged tables become a big advantage if you have to modify the data between the time when you load the table and when you turn it into a logged one. All these modifications won't have to be WAL logged.

Comment: There seem to be some speedup, but the fact that it takes an additional 60% of the original time to insert the data into UNLOGGED table, just to convert it back to LOGGED one is eliminating a lot of it. :/

Comment: Not everything. My idea of WAL was something that you write first, before attempting to start modifying data in-place, to be able to recover from the crash. So in my imagination `UNLOGGED` just skipped that part, and went straight to modify stuff. So turning `LOGGED` should just make things slower again. Now I get that I was wrong, and actually the whole data format was different or something like this.

Still, I don't understand why is so hard for Postgresql to give me fast writes, when all I'm doing is basically appending data, and I'm willing to sacrofice anything, and bend-over backwards.

Comment: No, you got it perfectly right. But imagine you have to recover from a crash that happened after you change the table from unlogged to logged, but before the next checkpoint could complete. How would you recover the table without having it in WAL?

Comment: As far as I can tell, all the data is written into disk when I do `ALTER x SET LOGGED;` I haven't tried doing a single write yet, so everything is consistent on the disk. I would hope that only the subsequent writes are going to bring only necessary parts into WAL, or something like that. In other words: I would hope that WAL is going to be incremental after I've turned it on.

Comment: It is the WAL that is written during `ALTER TABLE ... SET LOGGED`, not the table itself. Table data are persisted during a checkpoint. The unlogged table may still be all in dirty blocks in cache until the checkpoint.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. I really appreciate it.